# Django: how to route URL requests to django.contrib.admin functions

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like Django to return the same response for requests to `/myapp/add` as `/admin/myapp/mymodel/add`.

`myproject/myapp/models.py` defines the model and `myapp/admin.py` registers with `django.contrib.admin`.

`myproject/myapp/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
  ...
```

`myproject/myapp/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

I am stuck on how to route the request to `django.contrib.admin` in the project's `urlpatterns`:

`myproject/myproject/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home'),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^myapp/add', ??????), 
]
```

From printing the return from `resolve('/admin/myapp/mymodel/add/')` this looks like part of the answer:

```
ResolverMatch(func=django.contrib.admin.options.add_view, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=myapp_mymodel_add, app_names=['admin'], namespaces=['admin'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well let me say that seems like a weird thing to do, but anyway:

in the file: `django.contrib.admin.options.py` we see:

```
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
```

we see that the `add` view returns

```
_changeform_view()
```

which uses the template

```
django/contrib/admin/templates/change_form.html
```

So you would want to render that template in your view.

but it would be missing a bunch of context items,

so you would basically have to re-implement the django.admin.options._changeform_view

and then copy the template `django/contrib/admin/templates/change_form.html` to your apps' template directory

```
def admin_add(request):
  # admin.changeform_view code here
  return render(request, "myapp/change_form.html", {context{)
```

*ps. I assume the admin site view assumes the user is the "superuser" and not a normal user so you would want to account for that as well..*

Comment: Ah, ok -- thank you, this is useful. 

I naively thought I could map the URL path to the same view function and it'd return the same response to the browser. 

I hadn't thought through the superuser implications, but was hoping I could display the link to 'add object' dependent on whether the viewer was a superuser.

Would the correct way be a choice between:

1. Use ModelForm.
2. Just link to the default Django admin path via a template if the viewer is a superuser?